# How would i catch a JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, discord.py

i am new to coding in python and i am wondering how i would catch a JSONDecodeError and print a response.

I've tried this, if anyone is familiar with discord.py

```
@status.error
async def player_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandInvokeError.JSONDecodeError):
        msg = 'Player does not exist.'
        await ctx.send(msg)
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with the discord library / code you're using, please consider including a link or some more context.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with the discord library you're referring to - but either way did you look at the Python built-in [json.JSONDecodeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) type?

If all you want to do is see the error you could just do something like:

```
@status.error
async def player_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.send(str(error))
    raise
```

Comment: ```@status.error
async def player_not_found_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, json.JSONDecodeError):
        msg = 'Player does not exist.'
        await ctx.send(msg)
    else:
        raise error``` gives the same error

Comment: What error are you seeing? Please include the traceback.